# Can I shut down and restart pycharm debugger?

Tags: python, debugging, pycharm

I'm running a python script (which takes about a week) in pycharm debug mode and need to move my PC.
 I can pause and restart the script no problem, but can I pause it, shut down and restart the computer and then continue running the script from where I paused it?

Comment: I am curious to know, what are you doing that's taking **a week** to run.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in pycharms [help](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2017.1/stopping-and-pausing-applications.html),

> When program output is paused, the program continues running in the
>   background, but its output is suspended.

And when you powered down your computer, nothing *runs* in the background, everything *stops*. Which means that your program *will* terminate.

My tip for you is, if you thought it through, and you're sure that you need to keep the program running, do not shut down your computer since that will terminate it, you can download InsomniaX if you're on a Debian OS to keep the lid from sleeping.

Comment: I'm using the debugger, so pause suspends the program not just the output, I think. I guess the question is whether I can save the state of the program and return to it. I think you're right though that I can't.

Answer (score 0):

No.

Once you power down the computer, you cannot recover its state previous to the power shutdown; as the memory is cleared during a power reboot cycle.